# In C++ is it bad to store always positive integer in signed integer?

Tags: integer, epoch, signed

In C++ is it bad to store always positive integer in signed integer?

For example, seconds since epoch in signed integer.

Comment: But why? When will seconds since epoch ever be negative?

Comment: What programming language are we talking about here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can only be a positive  number it is good to store it in a unsigned int because that will force a compilation error when trying to assign a negative number and it allows you to have twice the size of the signed integer can store.

int: –2147483648 to 2147483647 
uint: 0 to 4294967295

So is it bad to store a always positive number  in a signed integer? No it's not bad. You allocate the same amount of bytes. Is it better to use uint? Probably yes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the integer size, environment, and application requirements. Storing a unix timestamp in a signed 64-bit integer is almost certainly fine. 32-bit may not be, depending on the date range your application has to deal with.

For most applications, it doesn't matter too much.